# Building a certificate to issue members once quiz is complete

Tags: 2013

Good Day Everyone,

Using SP13 I'm attempting to build a certificate that once they complete a quiz (this quiz was creating using multiple columns from a list with a couple of calculated columns to add up their score once they submit.) Currently the quiz sits in a button I scripted that opens the list in a NewForm.aspx. Once they hit save the list closes and populates into the list where the members can't see their result (to prevent seeing how others did on the quiz)

Here's my problem. I want to make a certificate that after they click save it will take them straight to the cert. It'll pull their score, the quiz name, date and time (these are some of the names of the columns from the quiz list), and populate this on the cert for them to save onto their desktop. By the way this cert shouldn't be able to be edited by them member.

The only idea I had was to upload a Word Document that uses lookup columns to populate the cert once submitted. Then building a workflow to direct members to the certificate upon them clicking save. However, I've not the slightest idea if this is possible in SP13, nor how I can make the certificate un-editable.

Does anyone have any solutions to this? Or any references that spell this out for me in black and white. I suck at interpretations so please be thorough. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Add content editor in your page and add java script that fetch result and time with JSOM, Generate PDF with [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript) or docx with [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899883/generate-a-word-document-in-javascript-with-docx-js).

Comment: What kind of script are we talking here? And how would I go about adding plugins and such?

Comment: visit this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2011/04/14/using-the-javascript-object-model-in-a-content-editor-web-part-kumar-abhishek-verma/) for more information